# Openvpn, 2 connections. Bind specific config to device

Tags: linux, openvpn, configuration, device

I use 2 connections and iproute2 with mark to route packages. But my problem is that sometimes, one connection is faster then the other and this messes up my routingtable.

Is there some way, in the config, to bind for example: "Config1.ovpn" to tun0 and "Config2.ovpn" to tun1. This way, I dont have to check the ip every time it connects and restart it until right config lands on right device.

Linux.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your client and server config you can use any device name you like.  So set a logical name for each vpn interface.  You will probably want to stick to letters, numbers, and the underscore character.  The names should probably be kept less then ~12 characters, they can be longer, but I have had problems with other applications.

My monitor vpn

```
dev tun_monitor
```

My VPN to home

```
dev tun_home
```

Device names are what I have provided.

```
# ip link
7: tun_monitor: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 100
    link/none 
16: tun_home: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 100
    link/none
```